# Use same variable name as inherited block name in Mako?

Tags: bottle, mako

I've stumbled upon a problem with inheritence in Mako. I'll try to illustrate the problem below using two template files...

**base.tpl** - has a named block *title*:

```
<title><%block name="title"></%block></title>
```

**foo.tpl** - inherits from base.tpl and sets the title:

```
<%inherit file="base.tpl" />
<%block name="title">${title}</%block>
```

The template is rendered (using Bottle) with:

```
...
return mako_template('foo', title="My title")
```

Now I expected the output to be

```
<title>My title</title>
```

but instead it becomes:

```
<title><function render_title.<locals>.title at 0x0346A1E0></title>
```

**Any clues?** Using a different variable name than the block works.. but I'd like to use the same if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this instead works:

```
<%block name="title">${context["title"]}</%block>
```

Does anyone know why?